# C unsigned `char ** out` to C# `byte[]`

Tags: c#, c, openssl, marshalling, dllimport

This is the function from libeay32.dll ([openssl project](http://openssl.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.0e-3/crypto_2ec_2ec_8h_a1a93f5739c093586ef83517b52b44a0c.html)):

```
int i2o_ECPublicKey (EC_KEY * key, unsigned char ** out)
```

How to describe it in C# (if I want to get a byte [])?

Code:

```
[DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static int i2o_ECPublicKey (IntPtr encKey, StringBuilder outPar);
```

I don't like this, because I think that the result is unicode.

**Answer**

```
        [DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public extern static int i2o_ECPublicKey(IntPtr encKey, ref IntPtr outPar);

        [DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int i2o_ECPublicKey(IntPtr encKey, int outPar);


        //Pass *out as null for required buffer length.
        int reqLen = i2o_ECPublicKey(k, 0);

        Byte[] outBuf = new Byte[reqLen];
        IntPtr unmanagedOut = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(outBuf.Length);
        int res = i2o_ECPublicKey(k, ref unmanagedOut);
        if (res == reqLen)
        {
            unmanagedOut -= reqLen; // because i2o_ECPublicKey add size to unmanagedOut
            Marshal.Copy(unmanagedOut, outBuf, 0, outBuf.Length);
        }
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(unmanagedOut);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe to do it manually, you need to use Marshal.Copy to copy the array from unmanaged memory into a managed byte[]. (Note, code is untested).

```
public extern static int i2o_ECPublicKey (IntPtr encKey, ref IntPtr outPar);

...
//Pass *out as null for required buffer length.
int reqLen = i2o_ECPublicKey(key, null);

Byte[] outBuf = new Byte[reqLen];
IntPtr unmanagedOut = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(outBuf.Length);
int res = i2o_ECPublicKey(key, ref unmanagedOut);
if (res == 1) {
    Marshal.Copy(unmanaged, outBuf, 0, outBuf.Length);
}
Marshal.FeeCoTaskMem(unmanagedOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the string with the correct Encoding by the use of `GetBytes`

```
StringBuilder outPar;
string result = "";
byte[] parbytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(outPar.ToString());
foreach(byte parbyte in parbytes)
{
    result+= Convert.ToChar(parbyte);
}
return result;
```